# Get positions nearby WP7(Bing map)

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I'm working on a WP7 application that should work this way   : After the user had checked- in, he clicks a button which should display the map(Bing-map) with  other users who are nearby.

What should the query be so that to find all marks which are +/- 1 (or any other distance) from him?? (Eg if he is at 22.515578,33.265897 then it should search for others which are eg at 21.515578,32.265897 or 23.515578,34.265897)

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia is your friend on the topic of [how GPS coordinates work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Position_calculation_introduction).

Without you telling us how you plan to get the data from the other users (local database, or service), your question cannot be answered more explicit.

Comment: Actually i'm going to extract data using web service.

Comment: Then you should explain what your problem is, related to that service.

Comment: I don't know how  to compare my position to each extracted position from  web service.

Comment: Oh, so *that's* your problem. Use the GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto.aspx